# Perl, экранировать знак вопроса

Tags: perl, экранирование

Есть задача починить файл, в котором встречаются подстроки типа " .", " ,", " !" и " ?". Нужно убрать пробел перед знаком и двойные пробелы. Написал такой метод:

```
sub someFunc
{
    my @s_trash_arr = 
    (
        [ "  ", " " ],
        [ " ,", " " ],
        [ " \.", "\." ],
        #[ " \?", "\?" ],
        [ " !", "!" ]
    );

    my $s_res = shift();

    for( my $i = 0; $i < @s_trash_arr; $i++ )
    {
        my $s_substring = $s_trash_arr[ $i ][ 0 ];
        my $s_replacement = $s_trash_arr[ $i ][ 1 ];

        while( index( $s_res, $s_substring ) != -1 )
        {
            $s_res =~ s/$s_substring/$s_replacement/;
        }
    }

    return $s_res;
}
```

Проблемы в [ " \?", "\?" ], оно не работает, программа уходит в вечный цикл, почему?

**Решено заключением в одинарный кавычки:**

```
[ ' \?', '\?' ],
```

Хотя теперь все работает с регуляркой:

```
$s_res=~s/ +([ ,.?!])/$1/g;
```

Comment: когда вы задаете `\?` в двойных кавычках то обратная косая обрабатывается и строка становится просто пробел-вопрос. Если бы вы задали в одинарных кавычках - этого бы не произошло. Но на самом деле ваше решение слишком сложно. Почему - напишу в ответе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы задаете `$a="\?";` в `$a` оказывается просто вопросительный знак, который разумеется в регулярном выражении несет свой смысл. Если задать в апострофах `$a='\?';` то в `$a` будет именно такая строка, как вы указали.

Кроме того: Вы пишите `while(index(...))` - это абсолютно не нужно, потому что регулярному выражению замены можно задать модификатор `g` и он заменит сразу все точки которые совпали с выражением (`s/ + / /g` заменит все двойные пробелы в строке)

И в вашем случае запросто можно обойтись одним регулярным выражением:

```
my $s_res = shift();    
$s_res=~s/ +([ ,.?!])/$1/g;
```

`+` в начале выражения обеспечивает удаление от 1 и более пробелов.

Можно даже без возврата назад в строку `$1` обойтись, если использовать *не захватывающую* проверку символов после пробела `(?=)`. Ваша процедура полностью может выглядеть так:

```
sub someFunc
{
 $s_res=shift();
 $s_res=~s/ +(?=[ ,.?!])//g;
 return $s_res;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде все усвоил, кроме того, что будет в $1, тут будет то что находится `s/ здесь? /$1/g` между первой парой // или нет?

Comment: Нет. В `$1` находится первое подвыражение выделенное в _обычных_ круглых скобках, в `$2` вторые скобки и т.п. `s/(..)(..)/$2-$1/` из строки ABCD сделает CD-AB. Я написал _обычные_ скобки, потому как бывают специальные, вот типа тех `(?= )` не захватывающих, или например `(?: )` выделяющие, но не формирующие переменную `$номер`

Comment: Спасибо большое! теперь понял.

Comment: Можете экспериментировать с регулярками вот тут https://regex101.com/r/fE8vT5/1  И в принципе все возможности в википедии по "регулярные выражения" описаны. Многие вещи, типа забегающих вперед/назад условий используются не очень часто и помнить наизусть их сложно. пока простые осваивайте. Но статью ту в вики лучше всю просто прочитайте, что бы представлять возможности.

Comment: И если мой ответ вас устроил, поставьте галочку под стрелками голосования за ответ :)

Comment: Простите, не так часто сюда захожу, совсем забыл про рейтинги :)

Answer (score 3):

Операция удаления двойного пробела и пробелов перед символами `,`, `.`, `?`, `!` может быть выполнена следующей операцией

```
$source =~ s/ +([ ,\.?!])/$1/g;
```

В выражении поиска отыскивается пробел (первое `\s`), за которым следует один из символов из набора `[\s,\.?!]`. Выражение, заключённое в круглые скобки `()` затем подставляется в выражении замены на место `$1` (в случае более сложной подстановки, например, `$100`, операция не будет выполнена, поскольку будет выполняться поиск подвыражения с номером 100, чтобы подставить подвыражение с номером 1 и добавить к нему справа два нуля, следует использовать `${1}00`).  Таким образом, будет подставлено всё найденое выражение за исключением начального пробела.  Параметр `g` выполняет повторный поиск до тех пор, пока не будет нечего заменять.

Примечание: этот код позволяет убрать не только два пробела, но и любую последовательность из более чем одного пробела, в том числе перед символами из набора (последовательно убирая по одному пробелу).

Что касается Вашего кода, то операция повторного поиска `while` может быть реализована параметром `g` поиска.

Comment: `$source =~ s/ ([ ,\.?!])/${1}/g;` это у меня не срабатывает, но работает если заменить `${1}` на `$1`

Comment: У него тут еще `+` нет после пробела, поэтому 3 пробела подряд превратятся в 2, а не в 1, как было задумано